# Why is time frozen here? Can I get seconds since 1970 freshly called each time?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, date, time

In code that is run repeatedly on my iOS app, I have:

```
// int timeStampMilliseconds = (ceil([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000.0));
// double timeStampMilliseconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000.0;
// double timeStampMilliseconds = CACurrentMediaTime() * 1000;
double timeStampMilliseconds = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() * 1000.0;
double hours = fmodf(timeStampMilliseconds, 86400000) / 3600000.0;
double minutes = fmodf(timeStampMilliseconds, 3600000) / 60000.0;
double seconds = fmodf(timeStampMilliseconds, 60000) / 1000.0;
NSLog(@"Milliseconds: %lf, Hours: %lf, minutes: %lf, seconds: %lf", timeStampMilliseconds, hours, minutes, seconds);
```

The three ways that I am aware of to get a time are `[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970`, `CACurrentMediaTime()`, and `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()`

When I run them, timeIntervalSince1970 and CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent get the UTC time to within seconds... but strangely, when the log statement is reached, the milleseconds go up at an appropriate rate, but the hours, minutes, and seconds are frozen at the time they were started. The clock hands don't move.

CACurrentMediaTime displays more of what one would expect; it accurately tells how much time has elapsed since some time marker, meaning that seconds, minutes, and hours all go up.

I think I could make a workaround behavior to have the initializer initialize a constant to TimeIntervalSince1970 minus CACurrentMediaTime, and then in the quoted code work add the saved constant and CACurrentMediaTime. But I would like to know what is going on and why, for two out of the three timekeeping methods, the raw number of milliseconds feeding into hours, minutes, and seconds updates, but the hours, minutes, and seconds are frozen.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a double use `fmod()` not `fmodf()`.
The format probably wants to be: `%0.f` not `%lf`.

The fact that the Milliseconds display is correct indicated the problem must be in the math for the other units, not the time methods.

Simpler code:

```
double timeStampSeconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
double hours   = fmod(timeStampSeconds / 86400, 24);
double minutes = fmod(timeStampSeconds /  3600, 60);
double seconds = fmod(timeStampSeconds,     60);
NSLog(@"Milliseconds: %lf, Hours: %.0f, minutes: %.0f, seconds: %.0f", timeStampSeconds * 1000.0, hours, minutes, seconds);
```

But all in all use the Cocoa methods such as `NSDateComponents` and `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: Better than what I asked for. Thanks!